# The "post" method in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I created three files:

2- view.py :

```
class AddTeamView(View):
    def get (self, request):
        form = TeamForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'add_team.html', context)
```

1-forms.py:

```
class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField( max_length='100')
    details = forms.CharField(max_length='250')
```

3-add_team.html:

-here there is another file called "base.html"

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
add team
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="/add_team/" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

     <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>  

{% endblock %}
```

and i went to cmd and entered the server "python manage.py runserver"

it appeared on the browser:

"This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405"

Comment: implement a `post` method inside your view.

Comment: Please add full `error traceback`

Comment: [Method Not Allowed: /add_team/
[20/Sep/2018 01:51:00] "POST /add_team/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
[20/Sep/2018 01:52:56] "GET /add_team/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2286
Method Not Allowed (POST): /add_team/
Method Not Allowed: /add_team/
[20/Sep/2018 01:53:02] "POST /add_team/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
[20/Sep/2018 01:53:04] "GET /add_team/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2286

Comment: This is logical, since you did not define a `post(..)` function. I think it is however better to use a `CreateView` here.

Comment: Give me your models.py code and help you or i can post my answer and you addapt it with your scenario...

Answer (score 0):

A view can support methods like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc. given the *corresponding method* exists, so the view should have a `.get(..)`, `.post(..)`, `.put(..)`, etc. function.

Here you only implemented a `def get(self, request)`, and so `POST` requests are not allowed.

Based on the data you however show, this looks like the typical usecase of a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView). The idea of these views is to encapsulate common scenario's such that by overriding a few attributes, one creates a view that is tailored towards a specific case, like:

```
class AddTeamView(CreateView):
    form_class = TeamForm
    template_name = 'add_team.html'
    success_url = '/some/success_url'
```

The `TeamForm` should probably be a `ModelForm`, or at least a `Form` where you override the `.save(..)` function to properly save your data to the database, since right now, the form is not doing anything (well it receives the data, but after validation, it throws it away).

You might want to override the `form_valid(..)` function in case you do *not* want to redirect to the `success_url`. Furthermore it is very common that the `success_url` is resolved lazily from a given view name, like:

```
class AddTeamView(CreateView):
    form_class = TeamForm
    template_name = 'add_team.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

So, we don’t need to do a conditional to check if the request is a POST or if it’s a GET:

Your ***views.py:***

```
from django.views.generic import View

class AddTeamView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_tm = TeamModel(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], details=form.cleaned_data['details'])
            new_tm.save()
            return redirect('team_list')
        return render(request, 'add_team.html', {'form': form})

    def get(self, request):
        form = TeamForm()
        return render(request, 'add_team.html', {'form': form})
```

Hope this help you...

Comment: AttributeError: 'TeamForm' object has no attribute 'save'
[20/Sep/2018 02:51:21] "POST /add_team/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78043

Comment: Ok ! Create modelForm because i considered that Your TeamForm is Model form. I adited my answer with this....